# Implement PropertyChanged For navigation properties

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have some entities with navigation properties 
some of those entities are used to bind to some DataGrids.

My problem is if I assign a  new value to a navigation property it doesn't reflect his new values in the UI.

Something like this:

```
public partial class Movimientos : BaseModel
{
    public Movimientos()
    {
    }
    private Nullable<int> _intIdBodega;
    public Nullable<int> IntIdBodega 
    { 
        get { return _intIdBodega; } 
        set { SetProperty(ref _intIdBodega, value); } 
    } 

    public virtual INV_Bodegas INV_Bodegas { get; set; }
}

public class viewModel
{
    public viewmodel()
    {
        Movimientos mv = new Movimientos();
        mv.INV_Bodegas = db.INV_Bodegas.First();
    }   
}
```

That way It doesn't reflect on the UI the changes at `mv.INV_Bodegas`. But if I reimplement the navigation property as this:

```
public partial class Movimientos : BaseModel
{
    . . .

    private INV_Bodegas _INV_Bodegas;
    public virtual INV_Bodegas INV_Bodegas
    { 
        get { return _INV_Bodegas; } 
        set { SetProperty(ref _INV_Bodegas, value); } 
    }           
}
```

The changes reflect at the UI as I expect (Of course this is the way INPC works).

But My questions are about the performance and the boilerplate code:

Can this have a detrimental effect the performance of my app?

Is it correct to implement this through a T4 template to avoid handwriting the implementation?

There is another approach for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't really a matter of performance. You need INPC for your app to work, so the performance cost is irrelevant. You could forgo it and rely on clearing and repopulating the collections instead (assuming they are observable), but as long as there is a reasonable alternative this strikes me as a bad and needlessly coupling solution.

T4 is a reasonable way of generating the properties. You could perhaps also save the trouble in accordance with YAGNI and work with some kind of templating functionality for a VS plugin that enhances the editor, especially if your schema is small and unlikely to change in the future.

Comment: First af all tks for your time. As you said this is a **needlessly coupling** solution. Do you know another way to force the UI to reflect the view model changes when the properties are Navigation properties ?

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez: Not really, it's been a while since I last did WPF anyway. Code generation is good enough IMO.